# How to build SSRS reports with variable filters?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, reusability

I've got an increasingly large set of reports where the following pattern is appearing: the users want multiple copies of the same reports but with different filters. The layout, logic and returned data is identical but there are about 5 different mutually exclusive sets of filters to be applied.

What's the best way to accomplish this? These are reports on top of an SSAS cube and the filters impact the MDX queries so I don't think sub reports will work, unless I'm missing something.

Any tips on how to reuse some or all of the layout and report logic between reports would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just single parametric report? MDX queries can be expression dependent of filtering parameters.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating different subscriptions and configure the parameters on the subscriptions?